# SharePoint 2007 Versions.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need to modify the versions.aspx page...  No idea how to nor do I know if this is something I should do?!?  The root problem is on the history of our document we have effective and termination dates.  Termination dates are kinda of the issue as they are not reflective in version history (when you look at the versions.aspx page).  They are implied... but our users would like to see the termination date show up.  I figured I could calculate it but I would need to update the versions.aspx page (haven't done anything like this before -- new to sharepoint dev).  Alternatively I could create a new page to show history the way they want it and disable the ECB for version history...  any advice or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is not recommended to touch any pages that are used by SharePoint (that is not supported by MS). You can fall back to second option you said and go ahead and create a new Page that will do what you want, you might need to do JavaScript hack to make the ECB point to the new URL.